# Given a nonzero vector $x$ in a vector space $X$, can there be a linear function $f$ such that $f(x)\neq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given a nonzero vector $x$ in a vector space $X$, can there be a linear function $f:X\to\mathbb R$, which is non-zero for a non-zero vector in $X$?

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ is a $K$-vector space and $v \in V$ is non-zero, then we can extend $v$ to a basis $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ of $V$, i.e. $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ is a basis of $V$ and $v = v_j$ for some $j \in I$. We can then define a linear map
$$
 f \colon V \to K,
 \quad
 \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i v_i \mapsto \lambda_j,
$$
for which $f(v) = f(v_j) = 1$. (Here the notation $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i v_i$ implicitely uses that $\lambda_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$.) Thus there exists for every $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$ some linear map $f \colon V \to K$ with $f(v) \neq 0$.

PS: If $V$ is not finite-dimensional then this proof uses the axiom of choice to extend the non-zero vector $v$ to a basis $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ of $V$. I don’t know if the statement still holds if we don’t assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: Exactly. (This answer could be simplified slightly by making $v = v_1$, the first basis vector.)

Comment: Notice that the basis is not necessarily finite or even countable, and the index set not necessarily ordered. In the case of a countable basis I agree with you.

Comment: You're quite right. Never mind.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner But you need the axiom of choice for such basis extension. WIthout AC, the question seems to be quite hard.

Comment: @PeterFranek I am aware of this. I didn’t mention it in the answer because i thought it war clear. (It would have probably be better to mention it explicitly.) I also don’t know if the statement holds if we don’t assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Have you assumed a fixed vector v in vector space? What if we need to find a mapping which maps all non-zero vectors to non-zero scalars?

Comment: @Zahir Such a map does not exists if $V$ is at least two-dimensional: If $f \colon V \to K$ is a linear map with $f \neq 0$ then $\mathrm{im}(f) = K$. Because $V/\ker(f) \cong \mathrm{im}(f)$ it follows that $\ker(f)$ is a subspace of $V$ of codimension $1$; in particular $\ker(f)$ is not just the zero subspace. But if $f$ maps every non-zero vector to a non-zero scalar then $\ker(f) = \{0\}$.  If $V$ is zero dimensional then there are no non-zero vectors, so the zero map $f \colon V \to K$ does satisfy the condition. If $V$ is one-dimensional then any non-zero $f \colon V \to K$ works.